# How to find where specific function in C++ program is being imported from?

Tags: c++, import, include, header-files

so I have a function my_func that is being used in a C++ program.  I thought I knew where it was being imported from, but modifying the function in (what I thought to be) the source file did not result in any runtime changes to my C++ program.  This leads me to think that perhaps the function is being imported from somewhere else that I don't know about.  Is it possible for me to figure out where my_func is being imported from?

Comment: Use a debugger and step into it.

Comment: There are many reasons for this kind of behavior. Typo in the function name, wrong namespace, etc. Set a breakpoint in your code and debug.

Comment: This function is literally named `my_func`?

Answer (score 1):

1 / Is the source file with the relunctant function part of the same executable , or is it part of a dll  ?
In case it's a dll  a very common error is to  compile and link without problem, but the actual copying of the file does not work, because the dll is in used. Or you have compiled and linked in another mode (release vs debug, 32 vs 64...).

2/ Basic tools like grep & find are your friend under linux : 
find . -name '*.hpp' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -n 'my_func'

Even on very large base of code (2Millions of lines or more), this should not take more than minute

3/ On visual studio, you can narrow the search for the include headers , listing them for your cpp file with the option /showIncludes : it lists all the include header recursively. Your my_func must definitely be declared in one of those headers

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to not link the thing that delivers it.  This will give a compiler diagnostic about the item not being found, and some idea of the file (and function it is required in).